# Java is looping through whole code 3 times

Tags: java, loops, pdf, exception

I wrote some code to put stamps on all pages of a PDF file with the email and IP that were passed as parameters from PHP. I have a few questions. Please see below.

CODE:

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("User ID: " + args[0]);

    try {
        Helper.sortposition(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4], args[5]);
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        String code = "PARAMETER MISSING FROM PHP";
        log.error(code);
    }
}
}
```

**Helper.java**

```
public class Helper {

public static void sortposition(String id, String email, String ip, String originalpdf, String newpdf, String report) throws IOException {

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream in = null;
    String hxStr, hyStr, fxStr, fyStr, fhStr, ffStr;
    Float hx, hy, fx, fy, fh, ff;
        /*  hx= Header "x" position
            hy= Header "y" position
            fx= Footer "x" position
            fy= Footer "y" position
            fh= Font size on the Header (Font Header)
            ff= Font size on the Footer (Font Footer) */

    String colour;

    in = Helper.class.getResourceAsStream("files/config.properties");
    prop.load(in);

    switch (report) {
        case "1":
            fhStr = prop.getProperty("fh1");
            ffStr = prop.getProperty("ff1");
            colour = prop.getProperty("type1rgb");
            hxStr = prop.getProperty("type1hx");
            hyStr = prop.getProperty("type1hy");
            fxStr = prop.getProperty("type1fx");
            fyStr = prop.getProperty("type1fy");
            fh = Float.parseFloat(fhStr);
            ff = Float.parseFloat(ffStr);
            hx = Float.parseFloat(hxStr);
            hy = Float.parseFloat(hyStr);
            fx = Float.parseFloat(fxStr);
            fy = Float.parseFloat(fyStr);
            break;
        case "2":
            fhStr = prop.getProperty("fh2");
            ffStr = prop.getProperty("ff2");
            colour = prop.getProperty("type2rgb");
            hxStr = prop.getProperty("type2hx");
            hyStr = prop.getProperty("type2hy");
            fxStr = prop.getProperty("type2fx");
            fyStr = prop.getProperty("type2fy");
            fh = Float.parseFloat(fhStr);
            ff = Float.parseFloat(ffStr);
            hx = Float.parseFloat(hxStr);
            hy = Float.parseFloat(hyStr);
            fx = Float.parseFloat(fxStr);
            fy = Float.parseFloat(fyStr);
            break;
        case "3":
            fhStr = prop.getProperty("fh3");
            ffStr = prop.getProperty("ff3");
            colour = prop.getProperty("type3rgb");
            hxStr = prop.getProperty("type3hx");
            hyStr = prop.getProperty("type3hy");
            fxStr = prop.getProperty("type3fx");
            fyStr = prop.getProperty("type3fy");
            fh = Float.parseFloat(fhStr);
            ff = Float.parseFloat(ffStr);
            hx = Float.parseFloat(hxStr);
            hy = Float.parseFloat(hyStr);
            fx = Float.parseFloat(fxStr);
            fy = Float.parseFloat(fyStr);
            break;
        case "4":
            fhStr = prop.getProperty("fh4");
            ffStr = prop.getProperty("ff4");
            colour = prop.getProperty("type4rgb");
            hxStr = prop.getProperty("type4hx");
            hyStr = prop.getProperty("type4hy");
            fxStr = prop.getProperty("type4fx");
            fyStr = prop.getProperty("type4fy");
            fh = Float.parseFloat(fhStr);
            ff = Float.parseFloat(ffStr);
            hx = Float.parseFloat(hxStr);
            hy = Float.parseFloat(hyStr);
            fx = Float.parseFloat(fxStr);
            fy = Float.parseFloat(fyStr);
            break;
        default:
            fhStr = prop.getProperty("fh5");
            ffStr = prop.getProperty("ff5");
            colour = prop.getProperty("type5rgb");
            hxStr = prop.getProperty("type5hx");
            hyStr = prop.getProperty("type5hy");
            fxStr = prop.getProperty("type5fx");
            fyStr = prop.getProperty("type5fy");
            fh = Float.parseFloat(fhStr);
            ff = Float.parseFloat(ffStr);
            hx = Float.parseFloat(hxStr);
            hy = Float.parseFloat(hyStr);
            fx = Float.parseFloat(fxStr);
            fy = Float.parseFloat(fyStr);
    }

    String delims = "[,]+";
    String[] colourstr = colour.split(delims);
    int[] rgb = new int[colourstr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < colourstr.length; ) {
        rgb[i] = Integer.parseInt(colourstr[i]);
        i++;
        Stamper.putStamp(id, email, ip, originalpdf, newpdf, rgb, hx, hy, fx, fy, fh, ff);
    }
}
}
```

**Stamper.java**

```
public class Stamper {

public static void putStamp(String id, String email, String ip, String originalpdf, String newpdf, int[] rgb, Float hx, Float hy, Float fx, Float fy, Float fh, Float ff) {
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("User ID: " + id);

    PdfReader pdfReader;
    PdfStamper pdfStamper = null;
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream in = null;

    try {
        in = Stamper.class.getResourceAsStream("files/config.properties");
        prop.load(in);

        pdfReader = new PdfReader(originalpdf);
        pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader,
                new FileOutputStream(newpdf));

        Font font = FontFactory.getFont("files/LTe50327.ttf",
                BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 0.8f, Font.BOLD);
        BaseFont bf = font.getBaseFont();

        int pages = pdfReader.getNumberOfPages();
        for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++) {
            PdfContentByte pageContentByteHeader = pdfStamper.getOverContent(i);
            PdfContentByte pageContentByteFooter = pdfStamper.getOverContent(i);
            pageContentByteHeader.beginText();
            pageContentByteHeader.setFontAndSize(bf, fh);
            pageContentByteHeader.setRGBColorFill(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);
            pageContentByteHeader.setTextMatrix(hx, hy);
            pageContentByteHeader.showText("This report has been prepared for " + email
                    + " " + ip + " Not to be redistributed without prior permission.");
            pageContentByteHeader.endText();

            pageContentByteFooter.beginText();
            pageContentByteFooter.setFontAndSize(bf, ff);
            pageContentByteFooter.setRGBColorFill(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);
            pageContentByteFooter.setTextMatrix(fx, fy);
            pageContentByteFooter.showText("This report has been prepared for " + email
                    + " " + ip + " Not to be redistributed without prior permission.");
            pageContentByteFooter.endText();
        }

    } catch (IOException | DocumentException e) {
        String code = "Problem with opening or saving PDF file";
        log.error(code);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (pdfStamper != null) {
                pdfStamper.close();
            }
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
        } catch (DocumentException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

It works as intended, but it seems like it is looping through the whole code 3 times.

When debugging it, I noticed that it runs normally the first time (Main -> Helper -> Stamper) but when it's done, it goes back to Helper class and them proceeds again to Stamper. It then does it once again before finishing. I'm sure it's something simple that I am overlooking, but as I am still a beginner in Java, I couldn't see why this is happening. This is annoying because when it catches an exception, it logs it 3 times.

When I purposely make it throw an exception to test the logger, it outputs the following:

```
17:22:12.541 [main] ERROR User ID: 10548 - Problem with opening or saving PDF file
17:22:12.596 [main] ERROR User ID: 10548 - Problem with opening or saving PDF file
17:22:12.635 [main] ERROR User ID: 10548 - Problem with opening or saving PDF file

Process finished with exit code 0
```

So my questions are:

1̶-̶ ̶W̶h̶y̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶m̶y̶ ̶c̶o̶d̶e̶ ̶l̶o̶o̶p̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶3̶ ̶t̶i̶m̶e̶s̶ ̶b̶e̶t̶w̶e̶e̶n̶ ̶H̶e̶l̶p̶e̶r̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶S̶t̶a̶m̶p̶e̶r̶ ̶c̶l̶a̶s̶s̶e̶s̶?̶ - FIXED

2- In Helper class, is there a way to use if statements rather than switch? Would it have any benefit? I have tried but it never worked.

3- In Stamper class, is there a way to catch IOException in such a way that I will know if the problem is when it's opening the PDF (originalpdf) or when saving (newpdf) and log accordingly? Rather than doing it the way it is now, logging: "Problem with opening or saving PDF file".

I will appreciate any input.

Comment: Looks like it is probably due to your colourString loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < colourstr.length; )
```

In `Helper` class you have this loop that is going to throw the exception multiple times. As many times as `colours.str.length` because it calls

```
Stamper.putStamp(id, email, ip, originalpdf, newpdf, rgb, hx, hy, fx, fy, fh, ff);
```

each time it loops.

---

A path to the solution would be to exactly detect what this loop is doing. Once you've done that, ask yourself if you need to call three times the same method. If it is still the case, no problem here. If it is not, it is up to you to make the correct changes.

Comment: I think one can advice the OP to move the `putStamp` call after the loop.

Comment: Thank you, this has solved my main issue. Spot on. Stupid little mistake.